# XLS to XLSX with time column

Tags: python, excel, converters, pyexcel

In an Anaconda environment, I'm trying to convert Excel files from XLS to XLSX, so that I can work on those files with OpenPyxel. I tried:

```
import pyexcel as p

p.save_book_as(file_name='test.xls',
               dest_file_name='your-new-file-out.xlsx')
```

But this is the error (last call of the traceback):

```
xlrd.xldate.XLDateAmbiguous: 8.158622685185184
```

After some debugging, I found out the reason is a column having time values, in a format like 2543:46:58. Since I have no control over the original file, how could I perform the conversion?

Comment: What happens if you just change by hand the extension from XLS to XLSX?

Comment: They are completely different formats, that's not a solution. Anyway, the raised error (by zipfile.py - required by Openpyxel) is about the file not being zipped.